# How to set up the dependencies with AndroidJunitRunner?

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing, android-espresso

I use gradle to build my android application.

I follow the doc (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html) to define the dependencies.

However, the `gradle build` always said it could not found some dependencies.

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugAndroidTestCompile'.
   > Could not find junit:junit:4.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1
   > Could not find com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1
   > Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1
   > Could not find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1
   > Could not find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1
   > Could not find com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1
   > Could not find javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
     Required by:
         :myapp:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1



Here is the gradle script

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
    }
    android {

        defaultConfig {
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        compileSdkVersion "android-22"
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'

            }
            androidTest.setRoot('tests')
           }

        dependencies {
            androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
        // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
        // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
        // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
            androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
        }
    }
```

Even though I specify the junit 4.12 in androidTestCompile, it still searches the library through `$android_sdk_home`, but not maven central as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your test code?

Comment: I do not have test code yet.

Comment: The dependencies block should be outside the android block.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I think the problem is that you need another repositories{mavenCentral()} section outside the buildscript section. I always use a root script for this and I was not sure. All your script looks weird, read [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide):

> buildscript { ... } configures the code driving the build. In this
>   case, this declares that it uses the Maven Central repository, and
>   that there is a classpath dependency on a Maven artifact. This
>   artifact is the library that contains the Android plugin for Gradle in
>   version 0.11.1 Note: This only affects the code running the build, not
>   the project. **The project itself needs to declare its own repositories
>   and dependencies.** This will be covered later.

**Previous response: other possible issues:**

Replace

```
compileSdkVersion "android-22"
```

by

```
compileSdkVersion 22
```

And you need to install and use a higher build tools version 22.0.1+

> Note: Always use a build tools version whose major revision number is
>   **higher or equal** to that of your compilation target and target SDK.

And  move the dependencies block outside the android block like [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

> The dependencies element is **outside and after** the android element.

Further information about espresso [here](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html).

I don't know the exact problem sorry, try a [working sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing) first, or wait a better response.

Comment: It does not work, it still searches the `$android_sdk_home`.

Comment: The first part is wrong. `androidTestCompile` is for the `instrumentation tests` and `testCompile` is for the `unit tests`.

Comment: It does not work. 
   > Could not find junit:junit:4.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/tumh/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar

Comment: Sorry, I'll read it better, i answered so quickly without read it well. Thanks Jared Burrows.